# Working out the binomial coefficient in python using memoization

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm trying to teach myself dynamic programming and was practicing a question from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-9-binomial-coefficient/. I first attempted the question in Java and my code gives the correct results. Java code:

```
 static int calculate(int n, int k){
    if(k == 0 || k == n)
        return 1;
    if(dp[n][k] != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        return dp[n][k];
    else
        dp[n][k] = calculate(n - 1, k -1) + calculate(n-1, k );
    return dp[n][k];
}
```

However, when I tried to implement the same thing in Python, I could not and am getting strange results, e.g. when n is 5 and k is 2 I get 13, not 10. I'm quite new to Python so may be missing something obvious but if anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated. Python code:

```
dp = [[-1] * 3] * 6

def calculate(n, k):
    if n == k or k == 0:
        return 1
    if dp[n][k] > 0:
        return dp[n][k]
    else:
        dp[n][k] = calculate(n-1, k-1) + calculate(n-1, k)
    return dp[n][k]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in your code is correct except the initialization. This might have happened because you might not be completely aware how lists work.

**Look at this statement and lets understand what it does:**

```
dp = [[-1] * 3] * 6
```

Operator `*` just replicates copies of whatever provided as list. So all the lists are essentially same and referencing to one list.

**To avoid this you must initialize it individually. Something like this:**

```
dp = [[-1 for j in range(100)] for i in range(100)]
```

So the modified code would become something like this.(Just has change in initialization method.)

```
dp = [[-1 for j in range(100)] for i in range(100)]

def calculate(n, k):
    if n == k or k == 0:
        return 1
    if dp[n][k] > 0:
        return dp[n][k]
    else:
        dp[n][k] = calculate(n-1, k-1) + calculate(n-1, k)
    return dp[n][k]

print(calculate(5,2))
```

As an advice, normally lists are not used for implementing memoization in python instead other methods are used which you might want to look on your own.

Comment: Awesome thank you that fixed it, thanls for the explantion too!

Comment: Happy to help .

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need of this condition `if dp[n][k] > 0:`.

Try it :

```
dp = [[-1] * 3] * 6

def calculate(n, k):
if n == k or k == 0:
    return 1
dp[n][k] = calculate(n-1, k-1) + calculate(n-1, k)
return dp[n][k]
```

Link : [Working code](https://ideone.com/9k5ZQr)

Comment: Thank you, seem to be working! I just wondering though, would this not remove the optimisation achieved by dynamic programming?

Comment: @HenryHargreaves No this is not even fully optimized solution because here you have n't handle the overlapping sub-problems that can be optimized further.you can refer the same link which you have mentioned in question itself